# How to reuse code in smarty engine?

Tags: php, function, smarty

In smarty, I  encounter such html code.**

```
{section name=listAll loop=$scope} 
 (input id="a1" name="from" / >
 (input id="b1" name="from" / >
 (input id="c1" name="from" / >
{/section}

{section name=listAll loop=$scope} 
 (input id="a2" name="from" / >
 (input id="b2" name="from" / >
 (input id="c2" name="from" / >
{/section}

{section name=listAll loop=$scope} 
 (input id="a3" name="from" / >
 (input id="b3" name="from" / >
 (input id="c3" name="from" / >
{/section}
```

Can I transfer it to a function like following:

```
        function RenderControl($i)
        {
        return '
        {section name=listAll loop=$scope} 
         (input id="a$i" name="from" / >
         (input id="b$i" name="from" / >
         (input id="c$i" name="from" / >
        {/section}
        } ';
```

Then call it in tpl file like:

```
    {RenderControl i=1}
    {RenderControl i=2}
    {RenderControl i=3}
```

why the following cannot work for smarty tpl?$smarty->register_function('RenderHtml','RenderHtml'); function RenderHtml($params){ extract($params); // $html= ' {include file="tke-pre_bid_scopeworkModules/Section1_Factory_to_Price_Optional_Configurat‌​ion.tpl"} ' ; return $html; }

{RenderHtml num=12}

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for [{function}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.function.tpl) which let's you define simple re-usable text generators from within your templates:

```
{function name=controls i=0}
  (input id="a{$i}" name="from" / >
  (input id="b{$i}" name="from" / >
  (input id="c{$i}" name="from" / >
{/function}

{controls i=1}
{controls i=2}
{controls i=3}
```

depending on the structure of your inputs, you might even like somenthing along the lines of

```
{function name=controls i=0}
  {$fields = ["a", "b", "c"]}
  {foreach $fields as $field}
    (input id="{$field}{$i}" name="from" / >
  {/foreach}
{/function}
```

This is a Smarty3 function. Smarty2 did not have template functions. You could extract the contents of the above {function} into a separate file and `{include file="controls.tpl" i=1}` it. Or, as @Brett said, write a plugin function for it.

---

The second part of your question is regarding the following code

```
$smarty->register_function('RenderHtml','RenderHtml');

function RenderHtml($params){ 
  extract($params); 
  $html= '{include file="tke-pre_bid_scopeworkModules/Section1_Factory_to_Price_Optional_Configurat‌​ion.tpl"}'; 
  return $html;
}
```

this will NOT include a file as you seem to be expecting. Whatever these plugin functions return, is written directly to the template output. Nothing stops you from doint something along the lines of

```
function RenderHtml($params, &$smarty){ 
  // create new smarty instance
  $t = new Smarty();
  // copy all values to new instance
  $t->assign($smarty->get_template_vars());
  // overwrite whatever was given in params
  $t->assign($params);
  // execute the template, returning the generated html
  return $t->fetch('tke-pre_bid_scopeworkModules/Section1_Factory_to_Price_Optional_Configurat‌​ion.tpl');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.prefilters.tpl in order to ensure the code gets evaluated before processing, so you can do as in your example.

You might also look at http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl

(The above is for Smarty 3)

Comment: why the following cannot work for smarty tpl?$smarty->register_function('RenderHtml','RenderHtml');
 
 function RenderHtml($params){
  extract($params);   
  

  //
  $html= '     {include file="tke-pre_bid_scopeworkModules/Section1_Factory_to_Price_Optional_Configuration.tpl"}       ' ;
  return $html;
 }

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the `$html = ...` line? Also, I believe template functions may be post-evaluation, so you may need a prefilter if you want to inject text that get evaluated as Smarty code.